# Como funciona o parcelamento da parcela com PagSeguro

Tags: java

Estou implementado a parte de pagamento com cartão de credito  porem quando vou colocar as parcelas ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
HTTP 400 - BAD_REQUEST [THE REQUEST CANNOT BE FULFILLED DUE TO BAD SYNTAX]
53041 - installment value invalid value: 5002.00
```

Acho que deve ser devido aos valores, como e a correta implementação do parcelamento?

Código:

```
    request.setShippingType(ShippingType.SEDEX);

    request.setShippingCost(new BigDecimal("2.00"));

    request.addItem(new Item("1", //
            "Notebook Prata", //
            Integer.valueOf(1), //
            new BigDecimal("2500.00")));

    request.addItem(new Item("2", //
            "Notebook Rosa", //
            Integer.valueOf(1), //
            new BigDecimal("2500.00")));


    request.setInstallment(new Installment(2, new BigDecimal("5002.00")));
```